# Android OneSignal setGroup null

Tags: android, onesignal

I'm trying to stack notifications with OneSignal on Android using the group key. Unfortunately we can't set it server-side, so I was trying to set it client-side with the setGroup() builder option in my NotificationExtenderService class:

```
    public class MyNotificationExtenderService extends NotificationExtenderService {

        @Override
        protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(final OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
            OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
            overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
                @Override
                public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {

                    builder.setGroup("myGroup");
...
```

This doesn't seem to work, however, as the notifications are still separated, and if I attempt to get the group key in the NotificationOpenedHandler it is null. Anyone know how to properly stack OneSignal notifications client-side?